# Make the second column expand by using getuikit framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, getuikit

I have two columns in a line. I want the first column is a text paragraph and the second column is a textarea.

The width of the first column is 10% of the width of the line; and the second one then expand to the right. So I put the columns into uikit grid.

By [uikit document](https://getuikit.com/docs/width), I have the code below

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
   Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div uk-grid class="uk-grid">
   <div class="uk-width-1-10" style="background: red;">
     <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
 <div class="uk-width-9-10" style="background: blue;">
   <textarea></textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that both two columns take the whole line. The width are not 10% vs 90%

[image: image demo]

[Please see the demo on stackblize](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjbznn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I want to use uikit framework(https://getuikit.com/docs/width) rather than general css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are block elements, which mean they will take up the entire width by default. Make them inline elements by defining the below css property in style attribute.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: I don't want to use customized css. I prefer use [uikit](https://getuikit.com/docs/width)

Comment: Use this class then "uk-display-inline-block"

Comment: But why the [uikit](https://getuikit.com/docs/width) link doesn't have such a thing.

Comment: I mean in the uikit example, they just use something like `uk-width-1-10` directly then it is okay instead of `inline-block`. Can you look at the example and show me in stackblitz?

Comment: Found 2 issues
a) uikit classes are not working. 
b) uk-width-1-10 class does not exists.

Directly injected uikit css to html and tried with uk-width-1-4 class. Works for me.

<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
 <div uk-grid class="uk-grid">
  <div class="uk-width-1-4" style="background: red;">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-width-3-4" style="background: blue;">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
<link 
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/css/uikit.min.css"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198452/discussion-between-devlasting-and-hui-zhao).

Answer (score 1):

use **CSS Grid Layout Module**

[check this site](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">I'm here</div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="text-align: right;"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use customized css. I prefer use [uikit](https://getuikit.com/docs/width)